# Finding the number of times an element occurs in Java

Tags: java, arrays, assert

```
public int howMany(String element) {
    int amt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < log.length; i++) {
        if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(log[i]))
            amt = amt+1;
        }
    return amt;
    }
}
```

That's the code I have currently. It takes the element that's provided, and goes through a loop counting how many times it occurs in the form of amt. However, when I actually run one of the tests that expects a number other than 0, it fails, since for some reason, whatever number is given to it by howMany IS 0, no matter what. Even if I change amt to 5 at the start, it's still 0 when a test like the following is run.

```
public void test_1_match_at_beginning() {   
    strLog.insert("string 1"); strLog.insert("string 2");
    strLog.insert("string 3"); strLog.insert("string 4");
    strLog.insert("string 5"); 

    assertEquals(1, strLog.howMany("string 1"));        
}
```

What is there I can do to fix this? Because as I see it, I don't know WHAT is even causing it.

EDIT: Oops. The test for the array version of the test was commented out. What was actually running was the linked version, which I hadn't changed yet. Sorry for the waste of time everyone.

Comment: Your function compares with elements of array `log`. Your test deals with `strLog`.  What is the length of `log` array?

Comment: post your insert(String str) method

Comment: Post [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

One big problem of your code is, your return is put in incorrect place.  You should notice that if you proper indent your code.  Return is now put in the for loop, which mean, after it checks the first element, it returns the `amt`.  Though it may not cause the problem you described (always returning 0?), this is certainly a big problem that you need to deal with.

Comment: Looks like an extra closing brace too.

Comment: @WilliamGaul ahhhh... good spot!  That's why I always ask my colleagues to have good indentation in code!